# How effective were archers/ slingers / skirmishers in Greek, Roman and Medieval Period?

Tags: military, roman-empire, warfare, weapons, greek

So it seemed that  from the accounts of Thermopelea,  Roman military strategy of waiting out an arrow storm,  and Knights holding out for hours behind a shield wall during the first crusade  it suggests that arrows were not effective weapons until later on, however it seems that archers and skirmishers  were a staple part of armies early on in Greece, why?

Answer (score 4):

They were fairly to reasonably effective. Otherwise nobody would have bothered with them in the first place. War is not about having the biggest baddest whatever. It is about applying force in the best possible way.

Light infantry were good or important enough to always have some in your army. And they were cheap, or at least cheaper then heavy infantry. A light infantryman had much less armor and needed less training to be reasonably effective. Often the poorer soldiers were found in light infantry units.

One job of the light infantry was **scouting**. Look for the enemy, observe them, go back and tell your commander about them. While you at it, you can - if the opportunity present itself - lob a few stones or arrows into the enemy.

Another job is to make sure the enemy cannot do whatever it wants, that's **skirmishing**. The enemy's heavy infantry has to form up first and keep in formation after that. Light infantry can make that difficult. Their harassment of the enemy can delay the formation they want to achieve, kill a few troops, and postpone his advancement somewhat.

At the same time, while you are in front **shielding** your own formation you prevent your enemy light infantry colleagues to do unto you what you want to do to them: deny them scouting opportunities, and harass your own troops.

It isn't the job of light infantry to stand and die on the spot. That's the work of the [triarii](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Triarii), or more general: the heavy infantry. As soon as the enemy starts advancing, or gets angry enough to charge those pesky light infantrymen they run away. Nothing wrong or dishonorable, it's part of their job. The light infantry moves through their own lines and reforms to do something else. Like harassing on the flanks.

Heavy infantry is there to stand and die if necessary. Light infantry is there to bother the enemy and live to fight another day.

Another job the light infantry did was **pursuing** the defeated enemy. They are light, remember? Meaning: carrying less equipment, thus can run faster. The enemy has to drop as much as they dared, which is pretty much everything. If they want to fight - and most won't - they will have to turn around and face your light infantry. That puts them at a huge disadvantage.

Most casualties didn't happen during the battle, but afterwards. That was a real important job for which light infantry was ideally suited.

---

*As this is as general as can be (the time period is huge) I put together just about everything that is not heavy infantry, for simplicity sake. **It takes years of training to become a really professional archer and more years to become a proficient slinger**.*

Comment: I'm not sure that your first sentence is necessarily true. They didn't have to be "very effective" to be employed, merely "sufficiently effective" would do.

Comment: The comment "*and needed less training to be reasonably effective*" is patently false for missile troops such as archers and, ***especially***, [slingers](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sling_(weapon)). Becoming a proficient slinger was possibly even more challenging than becoming a competent longbow archer a millenium later. Otherwise a great answer.

Comment: It would be nice if you answer had some sources and some specifics of weapons and armor particularly addressing the ability of armies in that time to just wait out and arrow storm 

hampering movement and pursuit of a routing enemy is nice but seems too limited to be useful.

Comment: @PieterGeerkens  why was trainint a bowman so difficult  you don't need to train for accuracy much if their just firing in formation so why does a bow take so much training?

Comment: @HaoSun: It takes years of training to develop sufficient arm muscle strength and a smooth release. Also while aim was secondary for massed archers, **range** was critical for effectiveness and again took years of practice.

Comment: @PieterGeerkens I added that in the footer. I knew someone would bring that up.

Comment: @PieterGeerkens  but couldn't arm muscle be built up doing most kinds of work in those days?  I'm not familiar with the concept of a smooth release in archery why is it so important and hard to train?

Comment: This is outside the topic, but it does take many years to be able to wield a heavy bow. hours of practice are required. You don't  need strong legs, you need 2 strong arms. And a careful aim. You don't learn that lifting dumbbells.

Comment: @HaoSun: Muscles strong enough to draw the English longbow deformed the archer's skeleton. [[link](https://theglyptodon.wordpress.com/2012/06/26/the-archers-bones/)] While a similar affect may be noted for other specialized heavy work, the affect is different for each such specialty. Unearthed skeletons of [Hungarian horse archers from the 10th century](https://www.forbes.com/sites/kristinakillgrove/2015/09/30/brawny-bones-reveal-10th-century-hungarian-warriors-were-accomplished-archers/#7fdb0c085f71) show the same affect.

Comment: The implicit claim in this answer is that during the looong time period in question, missile troops (slings, bows, maybe javelins ...) where used as skirmishers, not as "artillery". Which is the title of the question but not the body, which asks about effectives of missiles. Don't know how to clarify, maybe adress the claim in the OP that archers and skirmishers are basically the same? The answer is good IMO but the questions not quite clear.

Comment: @Jos 1) once your firing in formation in volleys aim is not that crucial short of shooting into the ground or overtop the entire army
2)   you make some point about preventing the enemy from manuvering but my understanding is that heavy infantry basically just draws up a long line possibly some reserves / flank guards and  just advances forward for the most part and light infantry does not really stop any of that
Pursuit of the enemy is interesting but battles need to be won first and for those purposes it seems that an archer/ skirmisher was just less useful than a heavy infantryman

Comment: like supposing an skirmisher carried like 20ish arrows and the enemy army literally just waits for all your skirmishers to use up all their arrows and then your heavy infantry engage are the few casualties and damage done to the opposing sides armor and shield worth the deficit in your heavy infantry?

Answer (score 1):

Archers were valuable during the Medieval period, at battles like Crecy. That's because they were then "formation" troops that made up the backbone of the English army at Crecy (and perhaps one-fifth of the troops fighting on the French side were Genovese bowmen. The Mongols also used archers (on horses) with great effect.

Archers were less valuable during Greek and Roman times. They were NOT formation troops (the latter consisted of armored men in phalanxes or legions with spears or swords). Archers, slingers, etc. were "skirmishers for "prebattle," (ambushes, probing attacks), and post battle (pursuit) maneuvers. Unlike medieval archers, they did not constitute the "main force" during the heart of battles.

Comment: That really begs the question why bother even training archers in Greek times?  As @Pieter Geerkens mentioned training an archer took a lot of practice why bother if they had little effect?

Comment: @HaoSun: First of all, you will have people who are naturally "gifted" as archers, whose talents you may want to employ.e.g. if you are China and have Manchurians or Mongolians on your border. Second, you will want "lighter" troops as "skirmishers" to begin and end the battles that are not as heavily armed as your "main force" troops.

Comment: In the Anabasis, Xenophon tells how the Greeks formed a square with the slingers and archers in the center.  The slingers had greater distance than the Persian archers, so they were used to keep them at bay and allow the Greeks to continue marching.  So while I agree with your answer for the most part, there were some formations used with slingers and archers.